# Listen to body click inside a view with backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-views

I'm creating a modal dialog like this

```
window.NewPageModalView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: _.template($('#view-template-new-page-dialog').html()),

    el: $('div#main'),

    events: {
        'click input[type=radio]': 'newPage'
    },

    newPage: function (event) {
        $(event.currentTarget).closest('form').submit();
    },

    initialize: function () { },

    render: function () {
        $(this.el).append(this.template());
        return this;
    }

});
```

and then I create it inside another view like this

```
addPage: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var modal = new NewPageModalView();
    modal.render();

}
```

this works just great but what is the best way if I want to close the dialog on body click or when pressing escape?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking when you bind events in backbone using the events hash they are delegated to the view's el, however you can still bind events to something else in the initialize method (in your case the body).

```
initialize: function() {
   $('body').bind('click', yourfunction);
 }
```

Edit:
As @muistooshort mentions, you will want to make sure to also unbind the event.

Comment: Ok, I thought that I could use the backbone events to wire this up but I guess it only binds to the view el, as you are saying.

Comment: You'll want to unbind from `body` somewhere as well.

Comment: You could also set your views el to be the body, but that's probably not the way you would want to go about it.

Comment: @muistooshort your right, I meant to mention that but forgot, I updated my answer.